# AriaSystems API - proc_payment_id

Tags: payment-processing, recurring-billing

Aria payments system method for create account is `create_acct_complete`, which must return some data with `payment_proc_id` field - the processor payment id, but I can`t get it - this field is always empty!

Who knows how I can get this `proc_payment_id`?
Does anybody work with ariasystems at all?

http://developer.ariasystems.net/apidocs/web/app.php/view/?id=83

Comment: We released a new Aria Developer Central several months back. Our API documentation is current and can be found at https://developer.ariasystems.net/ If you have any additional questions about our APIs you can contact your account manager by dialing our main number, who will be sure to connect you with any necessary information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told by Aria that their online documentation is not up to date.

The best resource that I've gotten from them is a bunch of PDF's spanning all versions of their API 6.1-6.4, which do not allow republishing without their written consent.

In any case, based on my understanding this `proc_payment_id` value should be returned when you are invoicing in unison with the `create_acct_complete` call. That is provide supplemental plans or a master plan that has a cost associated with the `create_acct_complete` call.

This likely also depends on your payment processor you have.

If you're only setting the customer account up without any invoicing items it will always be return `null`.

Their documentation lists that the `proc_payment_id` value is a 1000 character string that is nullable.